# Criar conta de email com PHP através do CPANEL

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se é possivel criar uma conta de e-mail usando o CPANEL, mas não de forma manual, e sim de forma programática?

Preciso automatizar a criação, pois manualmente não seria possivel dar conta da demanda.

Comment: Só depende de como seu sistema de emails funciona. Muitos sistemas tem APIs para isso, mas cada um tem o seu modo de trabalhar. Da forma como está a pergunta, tem um numero infinito de respostas. Precisa [edit] e ser bem mais específico quanto à infraestrutura de emails que usa atualmente (e o quanto conhece dela).

Comment: @Bacco, primeiro obrigado pelo feedback, estava recebendo varios fechar() e ninguem havia comentado, não saberia o motivo.. Por segundo: Não consigo pensar que haja infinitas respostas, na minha mente parece Claro. Veja só: Tenho um site, xxx.com, e quero criar uma conta de e-mail nele, pro exemplo: alexandre@xxx.com, o PHP não tem métodos ou bibliotecas conhecidas para isso? pois penso: Cpanel faz isso, porque nao posso fazer? Pensei que era algo mais simples, como sou leigo nisso, talvez exista uma linha de pensamento mais complexa que não estou dando conta de acompanhar.

Comment: O problema nada tem a ver com PHP. Email não usa um sistema padrão de criação de contas. Cada sistema de email (que não tem absolutamente relação nenhuma com a hospedagem do site) tem seu próprio meio de criar contas. Um email Google funciona de determinada maneira, um email da Microsoft funciona de outra, o meu sistema de emails local usa uma terceira maneira, e assim vai. Com certeza o CPanel não conseguiria criar um email na minha hospedagem, por exemplo. O fato é que por acaso, quem instala CPanel e libera o recurso de criação nele, optou por um sistema de email compativel.

Comment: Agora, depois do edit, o que vc procura é isto: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+cPanel+API+2 - Mas ainda continua dependendo do CPanel, no caso.

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado, editei para tentar não colocar o tópico no lixo e aproveitar para tirar a dúvida que talvez alguém passa ou passará.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A documentação do CPanel orienta a utilizar a UAPI: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+UAPI

Versão suportada: 11.42 ou superior

Para criar uma conta de email, mostrarei um exemplo com a LiveAPI (PHP Class)

```
// Inclua a library principal do CPANEL
// O local do arquivo varia de acordo com o ambiente. Verifique em qual local está o arquivo no seu ambiente.
require_once '/usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php';

// Instancia o objeto CPANEL. (Faça apenas uma instância)
$cpanel = new CPANEL();

// Aqui invocamos o método uapi informando os parâmetros para criação de conta de email
// Criaremos o email sample@foo.bar com 50mb de quota (espaço limite em disco)
$new_email = $cpanel->uapi(
    'Email', 'add_pop',
    array(
        'email'           => 'sample',
        'password'        => '123456',
        'quota'           => '50', // Caso queira ilimitado, coloque 0 (ZERO)
        'domain'          => 'foo.bar', // domínio
        'skip_update_db'  => '1'
    )
);
```

Quando bem sucedido retorna uma string no formato `user+domain`. No caso do exemplo acima, `sample+foo.bar`.

Documentação: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/UAPI+Functions+-+Email%3A%3Aadd_pop

**Para a versão 11** até a versão atual (legacy): https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/cPanel+API+2+Functions+-+Email%3A%3Aaddpop

```
// Create the user@example.com email address.
$add_email_address = $cpanel->api2(
    'Email', 'addpop', 
    array(
        'domain'          => 'foo.bar', 
        'email'           => 'sample', 
        'password'        => '123456',
        'quota'           => '50',
    ) 
);
```